# How to make try-except-KeyError shorter in python?

Tags: python, exception, syntax, try-catch, keyerror

Very often I use the following construction:

```
try:
    x = d[i]
except KeyError:
    x = '?'
```

Sometimes, instread of '?' I use 0 or `None`. I do not like this construction. It is too verbose. Is there a shorter way to do what I do (just in one line). Something like.

```
x = get(d[i],'?')
```

Comment: You had it almost exactly right in your pseudocode

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
x = d.get(i, '?')
```

Comment: Something *like* that, or *exactly* that? ;)

Comment: @jamylak That's the simplest think that came to my mind to make the text long enough to be posted.

Comment: I know, just messing with you